# WCF service fails to open socket?

Tags: c#, wcf, iis

**Hi,**

I have a WCF service hosted in IIS with WAS(net.tcp) and a winform client that connects to this service. This works fine on all but one computer. I can see that the service is starting up when trying to connecting to it but then the client just waits, the login methods is never triggered on the service?

To make sure if the service is getting any messages I have implemented a CustomMessageInspector (IDispatchMessageInspector, IParameterInspector) and set a breakpoint at all 4 methods (AfterReceiveRequest, BeforeSendReply, AfterCall, BeforeCall). None of these methods is triggered? When running the exact same setup on another computer we can see that it is triggered correcly.

Pleas note that the WCF service is runned at each individual computer. If the failing computer lets its winform client connect to another computers WCF service(that works) then everything is working just as expected.

When turning on the trace and message log I can see the following error :

```
<TraceData>
<DataItem>
<TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Warning">
<TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnectionAbort.aspx</TraceIdentifier>
<Description>SocketConnection aborted</Description>
<AppDomain>/LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT/test-1-129666827401375509</AppDomain>
<Source>System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection/10479095</Source>
</TraceRecord>
</DataItem>
</TraceData>
```

Not a clear exception.

I have checked so the serivces is running(NetTcpActivator, NetTcpPortSharing, WAS).

How to find out more about this exception

**Edit1:** The adress to the service looks like this : net.tcp://localhost/MyDev/MyClientService.svc/Regular and if i try this URL in WCF Test Client it will throw an exception. If I instead try http://localhost/MyDev/MyClientService.svc it can generate all the service methods but there will be a red exclamation mark next to each of the methods?

As I said, the service and client works fine on all other computers, the only diffrence for this failing computer is that it is over VPN but that should not be any problem. The failing computer is able to run its winform client against my main service over VPN.

The service do got a connection to a MS SQL database but it looks like it able to connect to it on startup on the failing service. If the WCF service was not able to connect to the SQL database we would have another exception.

Comment: @user978511 > Pleas, see Edit1.

Comment: There seems to be a known issue with VPN and WCF:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/netfxnetcom/thread/18a70c5b-7d8e-4a22-8d16-2011290111d1
Is it an option for you to use HTTP or HTTPs?

Comment: Okay? But why Is the WCF winform client able to connect to my WCF service over the VPN? Its only when the WCF Winform client tries to connect to the local WCF service that this fails? If the computer is running VPN but both the client and service is running local then there should be no problems?

Comment: @user978511 > Thanks but its the same problem when giving the exact URL instead of localhost. I supose that the firewall is not in the way when working local like this?

Comment: @user978511 > exact URL is like 192.168.3.2/MyService/Service.svc. 127.0.0.1 is the same as localhost so that should not make any difference right?

Comment: Can you try if it works with HTTP?